# How to RPC from External Process to Emacs

Tags: package, emacsclient, server

How can I RPC from an external application into Emacs then have a function in Emacs handle the RPC?

For example, I would like to make a D3.js webpage with a dependency graph of a codebase, view and navigate the graph in Google Chrome, and clicking a node should tell Emacs to display a buffer of the given source file.

Minimal amount of code written would be nice, and preferably native Emacs functionality, unless 3rd party package is the only way.

Comment: This is something that is done by the Chrome extension "Atomic-Chrome" (https://github.com/tuvistavie/atomic-chrome/) talking json to atomic-chrome.el (https://github.com/alpha22jp/atomic-chrome).