# Send a command to Emacs from an inferior process

Tags: shell, ess, process

Is it possible to send a command to Emacs from an inferior process?  For my particular use-case, I would like to instruct Emacs to run the command `inferior-ess-r-reload-hook` (part of the ESS package) from an R session (an interactive programming language) that was launched as a subprocess of Emacs.

Possibly related:

- [How to RPC from External Process to Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/37527)
- [How can I query Emacs from a separate process?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54156)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54161/2370 is your answer. Maybe, you can use the `system` command from R.

Comment: I think that the answer in emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54161/2370 is specific to the Emacs server, correct?

Comment: You can use any Emacs as server with `server-start`. You can even give the server the name of the `R` session and tell `R` to contact that specific server.